# Why doesn't JQuery mobile do anything in IE6?

Tags: jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-6

Quickly looking through the code it seems most of it has been designed with IE6 in mind but it seems none of the script runs in IE6.

I'm not looking for full functionality. Just some of the styles you get once the script has attached class names. I want to provide support for IE6 users through a simplified mobile site.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: jQuery Mobile can have incompatibility issues depending on your browser or platform. Check the online doc for more information: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/about/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Why so old ie6 you are thinking about?

jQuery Mobile cant work well with IE6.

because it uses css3 and html5 which is not supported on ie6.